# Swift Bit array to Bytes array (UInt8 array)

Tags: arrays, swift, type-conversion, byte, bit

I have array with bits:

```
var bits: [Bit]
```

and how could I convert it to bytes array:

```
var bytes: [UInt8]
```

For example I have 280 bits and I should have 35 UInt8 in bytes array. I can think of solution where I take 8bits and check if first is true, if second is true and so and sum the results and have value. This I would do for every 8bits in my bits array. But I think this would be bad solution (it would work but with unnecessary calculations). I think there could be faster solution with some shifting and so but I am really bad in this so I am looking for help. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possible solution is to enumerate all bits in the array
and for all "One" bits set the corresponding bit in the `UInt8`
array:

```
func bitsToBytes(bits: [Bit]) -> [UInt8] {
    let numBits = bits.count
    let numBytes = (numBits + 7)/8
    var bytes = [UInt8](count : numBytes, repeatedValue : 0)

    for (index, bit) in enumerate(bits) {
        if bit == .One {
            bytes[index / 8] += 1 << (7 - index % 8)
        }
    }

    return bytes
}
```

The main idea is that for a given `index` in the bit array, 
`index / 8` is the corresponding index in the byte array,
and `index % 8` is the bit position in the byte. You can
use `index % 8` or `7 - index % 8` as shift amount, depending on the
desired bit order.

Example:

```
// 0110 0100  0000 1001
let bits : [Bit] = [.Zero, .One, .One, .Zero,  .Zero, .One, .Zero, .Zero,  .Zero, .Zero, .Zero, .Zero,  .One, .Zero, .Zero, .One]
let bytes = bitsToBytes(bits)
println(bytes) // [100, 9]
```

*Alternatively,* you can "inline" the calculation for each group
of 8 bits. You'll have to check which solution performs better
in your case.

```
func bitsToBytes(bits: [Bit]) -> [UInt8] {
    let numBits = bits.count
    let numBytes = numBits/8
    var bytes = [UInt8](count : numBytes, repeatedValue : 0)
    for pos in 0 ..< numBytes {
        let val = 128 * bits[8 * pos].toIntMax() + 
            64 * bits[8 * pos + 1].toIntMax() +
            32 * bits[8 * pos + 2].toIntMax() +
            16 * bits[8 * pos + 3].toIntMax() +
            8 * bits[8 * pos + 4].toIntMax() +
            4 * bits[8 * pos + 5].toIntMax() +
            2 * bits[8 * pos + 6].toIntMax() +
            1 * bits[8 * pos + 7].toIntMax()
        bytes[pos] = UInt8(val)
    }
    return bytes
}
```

Here, for simplicity, if the number of bits is not a multiple of 8, any excess bits are ignored. The same code can also be written a bit
"Swiftier" as

```
func bitsToBytes(bits: [Bit]) -> [UInt8] {
    return map(0 ..< bits.count/8) {
        pos in
        let val = 128 * bits[8 * pos].toIntMax() + 
            64 * bits[8 * pos + 1].toIntMax() +
            32 * bits[8 * pos + 2].toIntMax() +
            16 * bits[8 * pos + 3].toIntMax() +
            8 * bits[8 * pos + 4].toIntMax() +
            4 * bits[8 * pos + 5].toIntMax() +
            2 * bits[8 * pos + 6].toIntMax() +
            1 * bits[8 * pos + 7].toIntMax()
        return (UInt8(val))
    }
}
```

---

**Benchmarks:** Here is now a quick-and-dirty benchmarking app (code below), comparing the various solutions.
It measures the time to convert 10,000 bit arrays of length 256.
The tests were done on a MacBook Pro 2,3 GHz Intel Core i7,
and the code compiled with the "Release" configuration.

Results with Swift 1.1/Xcode 6.2 (6C131e):

```
Martin1: 0.0460730195045471
Martin2: 0.0280380249023438
Martin3: 0.0374950170516968
Antonio: 5.85363000631332
Nate   : 4.86936402320862
```

Results with Swift 1.2/Xcode 6.3 (6D532l):

```
Martin1: 0.0228430032730103
Martin2: 0.00573796033859253
Martin3: 0.00732702016830444
Antonio: 0.515677988529205
Nate   : 0.634827971458435
```

Code:

```
protocol BitsToBytesConverter {
    var ident : String { get }
    func bitsToBytes(bits: [Bit]) -> [UInt8]
}

class MR1 : BitsToBytesConverter {

    let ident = "Martin1"
    func bitsToBytes(bits: [Bit]) -> [UInt8] {
        let numBits = bits.count
        let numBytes = (numBits + 7)/8
        var bytes = [UInt8](count : numBytes, repeatedValue : 0)

        for (index, bit) in enumerate(bits) {
            if bit == .One {
                bytes[index / 8] += UInt8(1 << (7 - index % 8))
            }
        }

        return bytes
    }
}

class MR2 : BitsToBytesConverter {

    let ident = "Martin2"

    func bitsToBytes(bits: [Bit]) -> [UInt8] {
        let numBits = bits.count
        let numBytes = numBits/8
        var bytes = [UInt8](count : numBytes, repeatedValue : 0)
        for pos in 0 ..< numBytes {
            let val = 128 * bits[8 * pos].toIntMax() + 
                64 * bits[8 * pos + 1].toIntMax() +
                32 * bits[8 * pos + 2].toIntMax() +
                16 * bits[8 * pos + 3].toIntMax() +
                8 * bits[8 * pos + 4].toIntMax() +
                4 * bits[8 * pos + 5].toIntMax() +
                2 * bits[8 * pos + 6].toIntMax() +
                1 * bits[8 * pos + 7].toIntMax()
            bytes[pos] = UInt8(val)
        }
        return bytes
    }
}

class MR3 : BitsToBytesConverter {

    let ident = "Martin3"

    func bitsToBytes(bits: [Bit]) -> [UInt8] {
        return map(0 ..< bits.count/8) {
            pos in
            let val = 128 * bits[8 * pos].toIntMax() + 
                64 * bits[8 * pos + 1].toIntMax() +
                32 * bits[8 * pos + 2].toIntMax() +
                16 * bits[8 * pos + 3].toIntMax() +
                8 * bits[8 * pos + 4].toIntMax() +
                4 * bits[8 * pos + 5].toIntMax() +
                2 * bits[8 * pos + 6].toIntMax() +
                1 * bits[8 * pos + 7].toIntMax()
            return (UInt8(val))
        }
    }
}

class AB : BitsToBytesConverter {

    let ident = "Antonio"

    typealias IntegerType = UInt8

    func bitsToBytes(bits: [Bit]) -> [UInt8] {

        let initial = [IntegerType]()

        return reduce(enumerate(bits), initial) { array, element in
            // The size in bits of a UInt8
            let size = sizeof(IntegerType) * 8

            // Create a mutable copy of the array returned at the previous iteration
            var next = array

            // If it's the first iteration, or an iteration divisible by the size of UInt8, 
            // append a new element to the array
            if element.index % size == 0 {
                next.append(0x00)
            }

            // Shift all bits of the last element to the left
            next[next.count - 1] <<= 1

            // If the current bit is one, add 1 to the rightmost bit
            // Using a logical OR
            if element.element == .One {
                next[next.count - 1] |= 0x01
            }

            return next
        }
    }
}

class NC : BitsToBytesConverter {

    let ident = "Nate   "

    func group<T>(array: [T], byCount groupCount: Int) -> [Slice<T>] {
        // get a list of the start indices
        let startIndices = stride(from: 0, to: array.count, by: groupCount)
        // add `groupCount` to each to get the end indices
        let endIndices = lazy(startIndices).map { advance($0, groupCount, array.count) }

        // zip those together & map onto an array of slices of the input array
        return map(Zip2(startIndices, endIndices)) {
            array[$0.0 ..< $0.1]
        }
    }

    func bitsToByte(bits: Slice<Bit>) -> UInt8 {
        return bits.reduce(0) { accumulated, current in
            accumulated << 1 | (current == .One ? 1 : 0)
        }
    }

    func bitsToBytes(bits: [Bit]) -> [UInt8] {
        return group(bits, byCount: 8).map(bitsToByte)
    }
}


let numBits = 256 // Bits per bit array
let numBitArrays = 10000 // Number of bit arrays

func randomBits() -> [Bit] {
    return map(0 ..< numBits) { _  in
        Bit(rawValue: Int(arc4random_uniform(2)))!
    }
}

func randomBitsArray() -> [[Bit]] {
    return map(0 ..< numBitArrays) { _ in
        randomBits()
    }
}

let bitsArray = randomBitsArray()

func test(conv : BitsToBytesConverter) {
    let x = conv.bitsToBytes([])
    let startTime = NSDate()
    for bits in bitsArray {
        let bytes = conv.bitsToBytes(bits)
    }
    let duration = -startTime.timeIntervalSinceNow
    println("\(conv.ident): \(duration)")
}

test(MR1())
test(MR2())
test(MR3())
test(AB())
test(NC())
```

Comment: First method is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Interesting results... it would be nice to make a comparison with Swift 1.2, I expect noticeable improvements, especially for the slowest ones - I could do myself, but results would be based on different metrics because of HW/SW differences.

Comment: Nice - my solution is 10 times faster in 1.2, although still the slowest :) However the new swift version is really much better in terms of performance, there are significant improvements in all cases.

Answer (score 3):

That's a fun question. I look at this as two smaller problems: (1) how to split an array of `Bit` into an array of `Bit` arrays, where each smaller array is one byte's worth of bits, and (2) how to convert those smaller arrays into one byte each.

To solve the first, we can write a function that groups an array into slices of a particular size:

```
func group<T>(array: [T], byCount groupCount: Int) -> [Slice<T>] {
    // get a list of the start indices
    let startIndices = stride(from: 0, to: s.count, by: groupCount)
    // add `groupCount` to each to get the end indices
    let endIndices = lazy(startIndices).map { advance($0, groupCount, array.count) }

    // zip those together & map onto an array of slices of the input array
    return map(zip(startIndices, endIndices)) {
        array[$0.0 ..< $0.1]
    }
}
```

To solve the second, we can write a function that takes each `Slice<Bit>` returned from `group(_:byCount:)` and converts it into a `UInt8`. At each step it shifts the value left by one bit, then sets the ones bit if that element is `.One`:

```
func bitsToByte(bits: Slice<Bit>) -> UInt8 {
    return bits.reduce(0) { accumulated, current in
        accumulated << 1 | (current == .One ? 1 : 0)
    }
}
```

Finally, you can call each of these in turn, or combine them to get your result:

```
// 1111 1111  1000 0000  0000 0001  0101 0101
let bits : [Bit] = [.One, .One, .One, .One, .One, .One, .One, .One,
    .One, .Zero,  .Zero, .Zero, .Zero, .Zero, .Zero, .Zero,
    .Zero,  .Zero, .Zero, .Zero, .Zero, .Zero, .Zero, .One,
    .Zero, .One, .Zero, .One, .Zero, .One, .Zero, .One]
let bytes = group(bits, byCount: 8).map(bitsToByte)
// [255, 128, 1, 85]
```

Comment: `s.count` should probably `array.count`? – (Btw, I made some benchmarks and it turned out that this is quite slow compared to the non-functional solutions.)

Comment: Thanks, fixed! Too bad about the speed—was hoping that using `Slice` would put it on par since the array doesn't need to be copied. Do you have your benchmark code somewhere I could see?

Comment: As Antonio suggested, I have added the results for Swift 1.2.

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer a functional approach, at the cost of a more expensive computation, then you could use `reduce` in combination with `enumerate`.

The latter, given a sequence of elements, creates a sequence of `(index, element)` tuples. We need the index to know the bit positions.

`reduce` instead is used to reduce an array of `Bit` into an array of `UInt8`

```
typealias IntegerType = UInt8

let initial = [IntegerType]()

let result = reduce(enumerate(bits), initial) { array, element in
    // The size in bits of a UInt8
    let size = sizeof(IntegerType) * 8

    // Create a mutable copy of the array returned at the previous iteration
    var next = array

    // If it's the first iteration, or an iteration divisible by the size of UInt8, 
    // append a new element to the array
    if element.index % size == 0 {
        next.append(0x00)
    }

    // Shift all bits of the last element to the left
    next[next.count - 1] <<= 1

    // If the current bit is one, add 1 to the rightmost bit
    // Using a logical OR
    if element.element == .One {
        next[next.count - 1] |= 0x01
    }

    return next
}
```

The returned result is an array of `UInt8`.

**Update**
Forgot to mention that if you want to convert to a different integer type, just change the `IntegerType` alias.

Comment: *" at the cost of a more expensive computation"* – You are right. I made some benchmarks and this was about 100 times slower than the non-functional approach :)

Comment: @MartinR: wow, I'm quite surprised - I expected something in the range 2-10x, but not 100 :) Undoubtely what costs more is the array copy, which is done for every bit - and that's an actual copy, because the array is made mutable and it is mutated

Comment: I have added the benchmarking code and the results.

Answer (score 1):

Some cool code here @martin-r @antonio @nate-cook, but there also seems to be some correctness issues that I discovered while converting this code to **Swift 3** for my use. Feature of this revised snippet:

- Xcode 8, Swift 3.0, as run in a Playground
- Includes validation capability (commented out)
- Has Bit enum to represent Bit type. (Bit type was removed from Swift 3)
- Although this is still has the timing instrumentation, I have not tried to really test the speeds of the different methods. Seems we need to ensure correct results first.
- Only Martin1 and Martin2 coded. Other methods left as exercise for reader ;).

```html
Martin1: 0.112455010414124: hash 0
Martin2: 1.06640499830246: hash 0
```

Anyway, here is my code strongly based the work of others. Hope some find this useful.

```swift
import Foundation

enum Bit { case zero, one
    func asInt() -> Int {
        return (self == .one) ? 1 : 0
    }
}

protocol BitsToBytesConverter {
    var ident : String { get }
    func bitsToBytes(bits: [Bit]) -> [UInt8]
}

class MR1 : BitsToBytesConverter {

    let ident = "Martin1"

    func bitsToBytes(bits: [Bit]) -> [UInt8] {
        assert(bits.count % 8 == 0, "Bit array size must be multiple of 8")

        let numBytes = 1 + (bits.count - 1) / 8
        var bytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: numBytes)

        for (index, bit) in bits.enumerated() {
            if bit == .one {
                bytes[index / 8] += UInt8(1 << (7 - index % 8))
            }
        }
        return bytes
    }
}

class MR2 : BitsToBytesConverter {

    let ident = "Martin2"

    func bitsToBytes(bits: [Bit]) -> [UInt8] {
        assert(bits.count % 8 == 0, "Bit array size must be multiple of 8")

        let numBytes = 1 + (bits.count - 1) / 8

        var bytes = [UInt8](repeating : 0, count : numBytes)
        for pos in 0 ..< numBytes {
            let val = 128 * bits[8 * pos].asInt() +
                64 * bits[8 * pos + 1].asInt() +
                32 * bits[8 * pos + 2].asInt() +
                16 * bits[8 * pos + 3].asInt() +
                8 * bits[8 * pos + 4].asInt() +
                4 * bits[8 * pos + 5].asInt() +
                2 * bits[8 * pos + 6].asInt() +
                1 * bits[8 * pos + 7].asInt()
            bytes[pos] = UInt8(val)
        }
        return bytes
    }
}

func format(bits: [Bit]) -> String {
    return bits.reduce("") { (current, next) in
        return current.appending((next == .one) ? "1" : "0")
    }
}
func randomBits(ofLength: Int) -> [Bit] {
    return (0 ..< ofLength).map() { _  in
        Int(arc4random_uniform(2)) == 1 ? .one : .zero
    }
}
func isValid(conv: BitsToBytesConverter, input: [Bit], expected: [UInt8]) -> Bool {
    let actual = conv.bitsToBytes(bits: input)
    var bIsValid = (actual.count == expected.count)
    if bIsValid {
        for index in 0 ..< expected.count {
            if actual[index] != expected[index] {
                bIsValid = false
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return bIsValid
}
func validateAll() {
    let input0: [Bit] = [.one, .zero, .one, .zero, .one, .zero, .one, .zero]
    let expected0: [UInt8] = [170]

    let input1: [Bit] = (0..<8).map { _ in .zero }
    let expected1: [UInt8] = [0]

    let input2: [Bit] = (0..<8).map { _ in .one }
    let expected2: [UInt8] = [255]

    let input3 = input1 + input2
    let expected3 = expected1 + expected2

    let input4 = input2 + input1
    let expected4 = expected2 + expected1

    let inputs = [input0, input1, input2, input3, input4]
    let expecteds = [expected0, expected1, expected2, expected3, expected4]

    let convs: [BitsToBytesConverter] = [MR1(), MR2()]

    for inIndex in 0 ..< inputs.count {
        let input = inputs[inIndex]
        let expected = expecteds[inIndex]

        let formattedBits = format(bits: input)
        print("Checking: \(formattedBits) -> \(expected)")

        for conv in convs {
            let bIsValid = isValid(conv: conv, input: input, expected: expected)
            print("\(conv.ident) valid = \(bIsValid)")
        }
    }
}
func timeTest(conv : BitsToBytesConverter, bitsArray: [[Bit]]) {
    // Prime compilation, caching, ...
    let _ = conv.bitsToBytes(bits: bitsArray[0])

    let startTime = NSDate()
    var hash = 0

    for bits in bitsArray {
        let _ = conv.bitsToBytes(bits: bits)

        // Hash to compare results across methods
        //let result = conv.bitsToBytes(bits: bits)
        //let bString = format(bits: bits)
        //print("Bits: \(bString): Bytes: \(result)")
        //hash = result.reduce(0) { (previous, next) in
        //    return previous + next.hashValue
        //}
    }
    let duration = -startTime.timeIntervalSinceNow
    print("\(conv.ident): \(duration): hash \(hash)")
}
func testAll() {
    let numBits = 128 // Bits per bit array
    let numBitArrays = 100 // Number of bit arrays

    let testValues = (0 ..< numBitArrays).map() { _ in
        randomBits(ofLength: numBits)
    }
    timeTest(conv: MR1(), bitsArray: testValues)
    timeTest(conv: MR2(), bitsArray: testValues)
}
//validateAll()
testAll()
```

Answer (score 0):

for swift 5

```
func convertBitsToBytes(bits : [Bit]) -> [UInt8] {
    let numBits = bits.count
    let numBytes = (numBits + 7)/8
    var bytes = [UInt8](unsafeUninitializedCapacity: numBytes) { (buffer, initializedCount) in
        
    }
    
    for (index, bit) in bits.enumerated() {
        if bit == .one {
            bytes[index / 8] += UInt8(1 << (7 - index % 8))
        }
    }
    return bytes
}
```