# Serialize [Bit] to NSData in Swift

Tags: swift, performance, serialization, bit-manipulation

I'm implementing Haffman coding in Swift and to get benefit from this coding I need to serialize my one-zero sequences as effective as possible. Usual approach in such situations is to use bit arrays. Swift contains `Bit` type and there is no problem to convert sequences into `[Bit]`, but I haven't found any standard solution to get `NSData` from this array. The only way I see is to create `[Int8]` (which could be serialized) and fill all bits manually using bitwise operators, in the worst case I will lose 7 bits in the last element.

**So if there is any standard (ready-to-use) solution for [Bit] serialization?**

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28929804/swift-bit-array-to-bytes-array-uint8-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is NO.

Bit in Swift is implemented as `public enum Bit : Int, Comparable, RandomAccessIndexType, _Reflectable { ... }`. I don't see any advantage to use Bit type against the Int, except the well defined level of abstraction.  The minimal NSData instance use at least one byte (in reality the amount of memory usage depends on the underlying processor capabilities. Serialization is also just an abstraction, you can serialize your [Bit] as sequence of words "Bit with binary value One", "Bit with binary value  Zero", ....  To save your bit sequence to NSData and to be able to reconstruct it (unserialize it), you still need to make some kind of 'binary protocol'. At least you need to save the numbers of bits as a part of your data. If you use Huffman coding, you need to save your symbol table too ...