How to convert BitArray to Data?
I am using BitArray in my project and need to convert it to Data to pass it to writeValue(_:for:type:). Did not find corresponding method in BitArray, so should I replace BitArray with [UInt8]?

It depends on how the bits in your array map to the data you need to send.  It might be as simple as using pow(2,index), but sometimes the bits of a GATT characteristic  value aren't linear like that.

The internal storage is (essentially) an array of unsigned integers, but there seems to be no public method to access that array.

There doesn't seem to have a direct conversion, but since you can subscript/pop you can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28929804/swift-bit-array-to-bytes-array-uint8-array maybe?
